# TypeORM migration run command is not working properly

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to create my tables using TypeORM migrations. I am able to generate with migration script but when i am trying to run the migration script it is not generating the required tables.

My package.json scripts property looks like this:-

```
"scripts": {
    "typeorm": "ts-node -transpile-only node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "migration:generate": "typeorm migration:generate -n",
    "migration:run": "typeorm migration:run"
}
```

To generate I am using this command :-

```
npm run migration:generate testmigrate
```

To run I am using this command :-

```
npm run migration:run
```

The above run command also works but it is just creating **migrations table** and **typeorm-metadata table**. It is not creating the entities although **entities path are properly defined.**

Need help on this.

Comment: were you able to find out he solutions for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should include your `datasource.ts` file or your `typeorm.ts` file